# Scroll to id not working in Fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have created a script to enable/disable the full screen in web page (React JS). On the web page on click button web page scrolls to top. Scroll to top is working fine in normal web page but when full screen is enabled scroll is not working.
Also, I used the scrollToElement React JS package for scrolling but this is also not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import {FullScreen, useFullScreenHandle}

export const A = () => {
 /* Click handler to enable the scroll to root*/
 handleClick = () => {
   window.scrollTo( 0, 0)
}
 return (<FullScreen handle={handle}>
    <button onclick={ () => handleClick() }>Scroll To Top</button>
</FullScreen>)
}
    
In Fullscreen scroll is not working.
```

Comment: Please provide samples of your code

Comment: @RifkyNiyas just added a example script

Comment: is `<FullScreen />` you mentioned, a third-party package?

Comment: Yes @NeetigyaChahar

Answer (score 1):

The third-party library used `react-full-screen` has an implementation where when the `FullScreen` Component goes to fullscreen it sets the containing `div` to `height: 100%` without `overflow: auto/scroll`.

Thus, the element takes the fullscreen and the content overflows without scroll. So, we need to set the `overflow` correctly and set the scroll function to the containing `div` instead of `body`.

[image]

This `div` is the containing element when fullscreen is activated over it by the package.

Check out the implementation [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-solomon-rl9mb?file=/src/App.js). Open the preview in a new tab for fullscreen to work properly.